What are the benefits of using an external authentication provider for ASP.NET Core Web API?
I'm currently developing a Web API that will be used as the backend for a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid application. I'm currently doing research into different authentication methods to secure the API and I'm seeing a lot of references to Identity Server, Microsoft Entra, Microsoft AD B2C and ASP.NET Core Identity.
As I understand it, ASP.NET Identity is more of a framework for interacting with different authentication providers however I understand you don't have to use those providers.
My question is what are the benefits of making use of these providers? Does they enhance security in some way compared to just storing the user information in a SQL Server database for example and under what circumstances should I make use of one?
I've done my fair bit of research so far into these different providers however I can't find an answer as to why exactly I should make use of them.

Storing user credentials in your own database puts all the security-related effort and work on you - you must ensure there's no data leak, you must ensure no password can be illegally obtained or cracked and so on and so on. Letting this be handled by an external system dedicated to this task can offload a lot of security headaches from your shoulders, and thus make your overall system a lot more secure

@marc_s Thank you that makes a lot of sense. I'm currently trying to weigh up the best way of going about this whilst also providing suggestions to my client however I'm not quite sure myself.


My question is what are the benefits of making use of these providers?
Does they enhance security in some way compared to just storing the
user information in a SQL Server database for example and under what
circumstances should I make use of one?

Below are the points you can refer which mention about what are the benefits and when to use the providers:
Identity Server:
Benefits: It externalizes the authentication logic from your applications, making it easier to manage and scale. It supports single sign-on (SSO) across multiple applications and services.It implements industry-standard protocols for authentication and authorization, providing a more secure and robust solution than custom implementations.
When to Use: When you need to support SSO, secure APIs, and work with external identity providers. It's especially useful in scenarios involving multiple applications
Microsoft Entra and Azure AD B2C:
Benefits:They provide a managed, scalable solution for authentication and authorization. They support integration with social accounts, multi-factor authentication, conditional access policies, and more.They offer high security and compliance, leveraging Microsoft's robust security infrastructure. Features like multi-factor authentication, threat detection, and conditional access improve your application's security posture significantly.
When to Use:When your application needs to support external identity providers (e.g., Google, Facebook), require multi-factor authentication, or you want to offload the complexity of managing identity and authentication.
ASP.NET Core Identity:
Benefits:ASP.NET Core Identity is an API that supports user interface login functionality. It manages users, passwords, profile data, roles, claims, tokens, email confirmation, and more. It provides security features out-of-the-box, such as password hashing, session management, and mitigation against common attacks like cross-site scripting (XSS) and cross-site request forgery (CSRF).
When to Use: If you need a flexible, customizable authentication system tightly integrated with your application and are comfortable managing user data and security aspects yourself.
SQL Server database storage:
In this approach you have to manage credential and session info in your database manually. it is not secure and more susceptible to attacks such as SQL injection, brute force, or password theft. Managing password hashing, encryption, token management, and other security aspects can be complex and error-prone.
So using these providers gives security and reduce the risks. They also provide additional functionalities like SSO, social login integrations, and multi-factor authentication that can significantly improve the user experience and security of your application. The choice is depends on your application's specific requirements.

Spot on this was exactly the kind of detailed explanation I was looking for. Thank you very much!
